# Define dynamic the properties of an anonymous type

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

I have a dictionary with a key and as value an IEnumerable.

```
var rowsByMonth = dictionaryByMonth.Select(item => new
{
    Station = item.Key.DisplayName,
    Month1 = item.Value.FirstOrDefault(element => element.ColumnIndex == 0),
    Month2 = item.Value.FirstOrDefault(element => element.ColumnIndex == 1),
    Month3 = item.Value.FirstOrDefault(element => element.ColumnIndex == 2),
    Month4 = item.Value.FirstOrDefault(element => element.ColumnIndex == 3)
});
```

The question is how can I create dynamically the properties Month1, Month2,...depending on the amount of the different ColumnIndex. Maybe I can have elements with different ColumnIndex. The ColumnIndexes are variable. I need to have an anonymous type with defined properties because I want to bind it to a DataGrid

Comment: You can't do that with anon. types, because the compiler will actually compile it. Anon types are just syntax sugar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly

I think you need to use `Tuple` because you need flexible data structure

Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx

Sample:

```
var population = Tuple.Create(item.Key.DisplayName, item.Value.FirstOrDefault(element => element.ColumnIndex == 0), etc, etc);
```

And then you can get `population.Item1`, `population.Item2`, etc

Comment: Thanks, I need exactly that. Thanks